# ffmpeg width not divisible by 2 (375x500) error

Tags: ffmpeg, h.264, video-compression

i tried to scale the video to 375x500 using ffmpeg.

`ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -s 375x500 -c:a copy output.mp4`

Getting this error, [libx264 @ 0x5639d358ad60] width not divisible by 2 (375x500)
Error initializing output stream 0:0 -- Error while opening encoder for output stream #0:0 - maybe incorrect parameters such as bit_rate, rate, width or height.

I tried so many commands but i didnt get my solution.

Comment: Hi @KarthiKeyan, your question may be a duplicate. You can find your answer [in this other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20847674/ffmpeg-libx264-height-not-divisible-by-2). Basically, as explained on the shared link, when scaling the video you want to keep the aspect ratio and may use a negative number to have one of the dimensions automatically calculated..

Comment: @diogoslima I tried those commands but I don't want to calculate the width/height automatically, I have fixed width and height, I need to scale the video to exact dimensions.

Comment: “Width not divisible by 2” is pretty clear. Change the width to 376.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

libx264 requires width/height to be divisible by 2 when using the standard yuv420p pixel format. Refer to the many suggestions regarding how to fix the `not divisible by 2` error with scale/pad/crop:

- [FFMPEG (libx264) “height not divisible by 2”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20847674/ffmpeg-libx264-height-not-divisible-by-2)
- [ffmpeg : width not divisible by 2 (when keep proportions)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47989621/ffmpeg-add-watermark-libx264-width-not-divisible-by-2-853x480)
- [ffmpeg add watermark libx264 width not divisible by 2 (853x480)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47989621/ffmpeg-add-watermark-libx264-width-not-divisible-by-2-853x480)

However, if you **must** have exactly 375x500 then you have to use a pixel format that supports this size:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf "format=yuv444p,scale=375:500" -c:a copy output.mp4
```

Drawback is that almost no player or device will be able to play it (unless it uses FFmpeg).

See the [format](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#format) and [scale](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#scale) filter documentation and the output of `ffmpeg -pix_fmts` for more info.

Comment: thanks, its converting but the pixel format differs as you said.